Capacitor 6.1.x on both Android and iOS http connection always return CORS error
I am encountering an issue with Capacitor 6.1.0 on both Android and iOS platforms:
When using Android Studio and Xcode, I receive the following error message: "Access to fetch at 'https://myserver.app' from origin 'https://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
Environment: Vue 3.4 with Axios.
I am confident that the CORS configurations on both the server side and the Ionic app are correctly set up.
reference URL : https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors
This issue does not occur with Capacitor versions 5.x or 6.0.0 on Android/iOS, nor does it appear when using Capacitor 6.1.0 in the browser on Windows.
Has anyone successfully resolved this issue?

I have already resolved this issue.

After extensively testing various versions of Capacitor, I discovered that the issue was not related to Capacitor itself. Instead, it stemmed from a recent change in my Nginx configuration. Specifically, the problem was caused by the following configuration:
map $http_origin $cors_origin {
    # Default is not allowed
    default "";

    # Allowed domains
    "~^https?://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$" "$http_origin";
    "~^capacitor://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$" "$http_origin";
    "~^ionic://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$" "$http_origin";
}

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $cors_origin;

This configuration caused Capacitor HTTP connections to fail with CORS errors, even though preflight OPTIONS requests returned normal responses. Removing the Nginx map setting and changing the add_header directive to add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*'; resolved the issue and restored all connections.
Could any experts explain why this configuration caused the issue? Additionally, how can I view detailed network information in Capacitor, similar to the Network tab in Chrome DevTools?
